# In this list, why are elements duplicated after appending?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

**Context**

I have a list containing dictionnaries. I want to "flatten" (JSON without nested values) all the dictionnaries of the list. To do this, I wrote a function, `flatten_json`, that works as expected.

Each output of the function is appended to a new list that will be processed later on.

**Code**

```
def flatten_json(cls, nested_dict, flattened_dict={}, superior_level_key: str = ""):
    for key, value in nested_dict.items():
        if type(nested_dict[key]) is dict:
            flattened_dict = cls.flatten_json(
                        nested_dict[key], flattened_dict, "{}_".format(key))
        else:
            flattened_dict['{}{}'.format(superior_level_key, key)] = value
    return flattened_dict
```

---

```
flatten_data = []
for accumulated_doc in accumulated_data:
    tmp = Utils.flatten_json(
               nested_dict=accumulated_doc['_source'])
    print(tmp)
    flatten_data.append(tmp)
print(flatten_data)
```

**output**

```
{'typvoie': 'RUE', 'l3_normalisee': '', 'enseigne': '', 'libvoie': 'PASTEUR', 'nomen_long_text': '', 'apet700': '95.11Z', 'codpos_cp': '59260', 'siren': '479454803', 'l2_normalisee_text': '', 'nomen_long_initial': '', 'nic': '00038', 'numvoie': 20, 'libcom': 'LILLE', 'cedex': '', 'depet_limit': ['02', '62', '80'], 'sigle': '', 'apen700': '95.11Z', 'l2_normalisee_nom': '', 'indrep': '', 'prenom': 'TONY', 'nomen_long_nom': '', 'id': '1a4e1ecca0488a04a8bccf9ffd4ec3fe7456b236db1eda54147c6551', 'codpos_bur_distrib': '260', 'l2_normalisee_initial': '', 'codpos_depet': '59', 'libapen': 'Reparation d ordinateurs et d equipements peripheriques', 'nom': 'MARTIN'}

{'typvoie': 'AV', 'l3_normalisee': '', 'enseigne': '', 'libvoie': 'DES MIMOSAS', 'nomen_long_text': 'AIR-C', 'apet700': '70.22Z', 'codpos_cp': '45130', 'siren': '823306030', 'l2_normalisee_text': '', 'nomen_long_initial': 'AC', 'nic': '00011', 'numvoie': 12, 'libcom': 'SAINT AY', 'cedex': '', 'depet_limit': ['18', '28', '41', '58', '77', '89', '91'], 'sigle': '', 'apen700': '70.22Z', 'l2_normalisee_nom': '', 'indrep': '', 'prenom': '', 'nomen_long_nom': 'AIR-C', 'id': 'b420b749064951b18ac95cba63d17a6aa74d9fe76856254279ab7665', 'codpos_bur_distrib': '130', 'l2_normalisee_initial': '', 'codpos_depet': '45', 'libapen': 'Conseil pour les affaires et autres conseils de gestion', 'nom': ''}

{'typvoie': 'RUE', 'l3_normalisee': '', 'enseigne': '', 'libvoie': 'NATIONALE', 'nomen_long_text': 'ECCETERA', 'apet700': '47.59B', 'codpos_cp': '74500', 'siren': '493769970', 'l2_normalisee_text': '', 'nomen_long_initial': 'E', 'nic': '00010', 'numvoie': 21, 'libcom': 'EVIAN LES BAINS', 'cedex': '', 'depet_limit': ['01', '73'], 'sigle': '', 'apen700': '47.59B', 'l2_normalisee_nom': '', 'indrep': '', 'prenom': '', 'nomen_long_nom': 'ECCETERA', 'id': '1769f88b368debbf7f4f4d3e22e4fcffb8792bc111d66f0fea701030', 'codpos_bur_distrib': '500', 'l2_normalisee_initial': '', 'codpos_depet': '74', 'libapen': 'Commerce de detail d autres equipements du foyer', 'nom': ''}

{'typvoie': 'RTE', 'l3_normalisee': '', 'enseigne': '', 'libvoie': 'DU VALLON', 'nomen_long_text': '', 'apet700': '47.91A', 'codpos_cp': '83320', 'siren': '823306113', 'l2_normalisee_text': '', 'nomen_long_initial': '', 'nic': '00015', 'numvoie': 1537, 'libcom': 'CARQUEIRANNE', 'cedex': '', 'depet_limit': ['04', '06', '13', '84'], 'sigle': '', 'apen700': '47.91A', 'l2_normalisee_nom': '', 'indrep': '', 'prenom': 'NATHALIE', 'nomen_long_nom': '', 'id': '11e6d4099333c5783a4e333de53904c4e031d87b75738005fed103c0', 'codpos_bur_distrib': '320', 'l2_normalisee_initial': '', 'codpos_depet': '83', 'libapen': 'Vente a distance sur catalogue general', 'nom': 'GAILLARD'}

{'typvoie': 'RUE', 'l3_normalisee': '', 'enseigne': 'MAIRIE', 'libvoie': "DE L'EGLISE", 'nomen_long_text': 'COMMUNE DE FRAILLICOURT', 'apet700': '84.11Z', 'codpos_cp': '08220', 'siren': '210801627', 'l2_normalisee_text': '', 'nomen_long_initial': 'CDF', 'nic': '00014', 'numvoie': None, 'libcom': 'FRAILLICOURT', 'cedex': '', 'depet_limit': ['02', '51', '55'], 'sigle': '', 'apen700': '84.11Z', 'l2_normalisee_nom': '', 'indrep': '', 'prenom': '', 'nomen_long_nom': 'COMMUNE DE FRAILLICOURT', 'id': '6d2e413d07a1877d543b796da92ba7772088481bf8a2c842c3b82ff1', 'codpos_bur_distrib': '220', 'l2_normalisee_initial': '', 'codpos_depet': '08', 'libapen': 'Administration publique generale', 'nom': ''}

{'typvoie': 'RUE', 'l3_normalisee': '', 'enseigne': '', 'libvoie': 'DE LA CORNICHE', 'nomen_long_text': '', 'apet700': '43.22A', 'codpos_cp': '91120', 'siren': '479454928', 'l2_normalisee_text': '', 'nomen_long_initial': '', 'nic': '00017', 'numvoie': 22, 'libcom': 'PALAISEAU', 'cedex': '', 'depet_limit': ['28', '45', '77', '78', '92', '94'], 'sigle': '', 'apen700': '43.22A', 'l2_normalisee_nom': '', 'indrep': '', 'prenom': 'DAVID', 'nomen_long_nom': '', 'id': '307830402c4302451f2a5e236f30b0ed9c3bd9155b345fc7195ed1b3', 'codpos_bur_distrib': '120', 'l2_normalisee_initial': '', 'codpos_depet': '91', 'libapen': 'Travaux d installation d eau et de gaz en tous locaux', 'nom': 'NOBLECOURT'}

[{'typvoie': 'RUE', 'l3_normalisee': '', 'enseigne': '', 'libvoie': 'DE LA CORNICHE', 'nomen_long_text': '', 'apet700': '43.22A', 'codpos_cp': '91120', 'siren': '479454928', 'l2_normalisee_text': '', 'nomen_long_initial': '', 'nic': '00017', 'numvoie': 22, 'libcom': 'PALAISEAU', 'cedex': '', 'depet_limit': ['28', '45', '77', '78', '92', '94'], 'sigle': '', 'apen700': '43.22A', 'l2_normalisee_nom': '', 'indrep': '', 'prenom': 'DAVID', 'nomen_long_nom': '', 'id': '307830402c4302451f2a5e236f30b0ed9c3bd9155b345fc7195ed1b3', 'codpos_bur_distrib': '120', 'l2_normalisee_initial': '', 'codpos_depet': '91', 'libapen': 'Travaux d installation d eau et de gaz en tous locaux', 'nom': 'NOBLECOURT'}, {'typvoie': 'RUE', 'l3_normalisee': '', 'enseigne': '', 'libvoie': 'DE LA CORNICHE', 'nomen_long_text': '', 'apet700': '43.22A', 'codpos_cp': '91120', 'siren': '479454928', 'l2_normalisee_text': '', 'nomen_long_initial': '', 'nic': '00017', 'numvoie': 22, 'libcom': 'PALAISEAU', 'cedex': '', 'depet_limit': ['28', '45', '77', '78', '92', '94'], 'sigle': '', 'apen700': '43.22A', 'l2_normalisee_nom': '', 'indrep': '', 'prenom': 'DAVID', 'nomen_long_nom': '', 'id': '307830402c4302451f2a5e236f30b0ed9c3bd9155b345fc7195ed1b3', 'codpos_bur_distrib': '120', 'l2_normalisee_initial': '', 'codpos_depet': '91', 'libapen': 'Travaux d installation d eau et de gaz en tous locaux', 'nom': 'NOBLECOURT'}, {'typvoie': 'RUE', 'l3_normalisee': '', 'enseigne': '', 'libvoie': 'DE LA CORNICHE', 'nomen_long_text': '', 'apet700': '43.22A', 'codpos_cp': '91120', 'siren': '479454928', 'l2_normalisee_text': '', 'nomen_long_initial': '', 'nic': '00017', 'numvoie': 22, 'libcom': 'PALAISEAU', 'cedex': '', 'depet_limit': ['28', '45', '77', '78', '92', '94'], 'sigle': '', 'apen700': '43.22A', 'l2_normalisee_nom': '', 'indrep': '', 'prenom': 'DAVID', 'nomen_long_nom': '', 'id': '307830402c4302451f2a5e236f30b0ed9c3bd9155b345fc7195ed1b3', 'codpos_bur_distrib': '120', 'l2_normalisee_initial': '', 'codpos_depet': '91', 'libapen': 'Travaux d installation d eau et de gaz en tous locaux', 'nom': 'NOBLECOURT'}, {'typvoie': 'RUE', 'l3_normalisee': '', 'enseigne': '', 'libvoie': 'DE LA CORNICHE', 'nomen_long_text': '', 'apet700': '43.22A', 'codpos_cp': '91120', 'siren': '479454928', 'l2_normalisee_text': '', 'nomen_long_initial': '', 'nic': '00017', 'numvoie': 22, 'libcom': 'PALAISEAU', 'cedex': '', 'depet_limit': ['28', '45', '77', '78', '92', '94'], 'sigle': '', 'apen700': '43.22A', 'l2_normalisee_nom': '', 'indrep': '', 'prenom': 'DAVID', 'nomen_long_nom': '', 'id': '307830402c4302451f2a5e236f30b0ed9c3bd9155b345fc7195ed1b3', 'codpos_bur_distrib': '120', 'l2_normalisee_initial': '', 'codpos_depet': '91', 'libapen': 'Travaux d installation d eau et de gaz en tous locaux', 'nom': 'NOBLECOURT'}, {'typvoie': 'RUE', 'l3_normalisee': '', 'enseigne': '', 'libvoie': 'DE LA CORNICHE', 'nomen_long_text': '', 'apet700': '43.22A', 'codpos_cp': '91120', 'siren': '479454928', 'l2_normalisee_text': '', 'nomen_long_initial': '', 'nic': '00017', 'numvoie': 22, 'libcom': 'PALAISEAU', 'cedex': '', 'depet_limit': ['28', '45', '77', '78', '92', '94'], 'sigle': '', 'apen700': '43.22A', 'l2_normalisee_nom': '', 'indrep': '', 'prenom': 'DAVID', 'nomen_long_nom': '', 'id': '307830402c4302451f2a5e236f30b0ed9c3bd9155b345fc7195ed1b3', 'codpos_bur_distrib': '120', 'l2_normalisee_initial': '', 'codpos_depet': '91', 'libapen': 'Travaux d installation d eau et de gaz en tous locaux', 'nom': 'NOBLECOURT'}, {'typvoie': 'RUE', 'l3_normalisee': '', 'enseigne': '', 'libvoie': 'DE LA CORNICHE', 'nomen_long_text': '', 'apet700': '43.22A', 'codpos_cp': '91120', 'siren': '479454928', 'l2_normalisee_text': '', 'nomen_long_initial': '', 'nic': '00017', 'numvoie': 22, 'libcom': 'PALAISEAU', 'cedex': '', 'depet_limit': ['28', '45', '77', '78', '92', '94'], 'sigle': '', 'apen700': '43.22A', 'l2_normalisee_nom': '', 'indrep': '', 'prenom': 'DAVID', 'nomen_long_nom': '', 'id': '307830402c4302451f2a5e236f30b0ed9c3bd9155b345fc7195ed1b3', 'codpos_bur_distrib': '120', 'l2_normalisee_initial': '', 'codpos_depet': '91', 'libapen': 'Travaux d installation d eau et de gaz en tous locaux', 'nom': 'NOBLECOURT'}]
```

**problem**

As you can see, the `tmp` dictiponnary has the correct value (it is different at each loop as expected). However, when I print the `flatten_data` list after the loop, each element of the list contains the very same dictionnary.

**Question**

Why is this happening ?

How can I change this code so that the list does not duplicate (if that is the problem) the last element in place of all the previous ones ?

Comment: Please show `Utils.flatten_json` too.

Comment: @AKX flatten_json has been added to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`flattened_dict={}` is your problem. Parameter defaults are evaluated only once, so when you don't pass in a dict the same one gets reused.

You'll want (sorry for brevity and formatting, on mobile)

```
def ...(..., flattened_dict=None):
    if flattened_dict is None:
         flattened_dict = {}
```

Comment: That is true. I have the expected behavior now. Do you know why this is the default behavior ? Unless I am mistaken, I did not encounter this behavior in any language I used (java, c#, js, etc.) So why would this be the default behavior ? it's so counter intuitive !

Comment: I was about to post the same answer ;) ... yes, it might be counter intuitive, but the default arguments are created statically in python. So best practice is not to use mutable default parameters, but use the workaround as described. This makes me think if this (unique?) behaviour can be used for something good in other cases!?

Comment: As a source for those who may need it: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments

Comment: Sometimes the behavior is useful, for e. g. caching.